Creating an index mapping from Json (Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch for .NET)
I'm trying to use Elasticsearch's .NET client (8.9) to create an index template that includes a mapping. I understand that I can configure a mapping, for example, like so:
var templateRequest = new PutIndexTemplateRequest("testIndexTemplate")
{
  Template = new IndexTemplateMapping
  {
    Mappings = new TypeMapping
    {
      Properties = new Properties
      {
        { "textProperty", new TextProperty() }
      }
    }
  }
};

However, the source of truth for our index mapping is actually a large json file, something like this:
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "_routing": {
    "required": true
  },
  "dynamic_templates": [],
  "properties": {
    "textProperty": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}

(The real file is large enough that it would be impractical for me to try to represent it in code as a TypeMapping object like the one shown above). Is there a way to use the .NET client to consume our json and use that for the mapping?
I've tried exploring the .NET client documentation, but it's fairly sparse.
